# Serial console on BeagleV-Ahead

Tags: command-line, u-boot

I am having trouble configuring the BeagleV-Ahead serial console on Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar. I am pretty sure I have the hardware and driver on the client set correctly, but I see only garbage go by.

Usually, BeagleBone Black sets serial to 115200 8N1, so I tried that. Stuff goes by, but corrupted.

Dmesg says

```
printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
ffe7014000.serial: ttys0 at MMIO 0xffe7014000 (irq = 4, base baud = 6250000) is a 16550A
printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
```

Note the zeroes... six million bauds? Where is this setting coming from? I presume it is the `console` parameter passed to the kernel… but where is the setting in eMMC-flashed u-boot, and how do you change it?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Doh. The distribution is Ubuntu 23.04. Updated.

Comment: Looks like `ttyS0` is both Console and a login session. The latter I can see from a systemd service (serial-getty@ttyS0.service), which is running.

Comment: I have not yet located configuration for either the console (presumed to be U-boot supplied string) or the TTY (systemd has a facility to bulk-configureTTYs, guessing it is there).

Comment: Kernel parameter string is in /proc/cmdline. console=115200,ttyS0 is the setting, but those messages in dmesg suggest the hardware is doing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with several popular serial-to-USB converters on this board, [documented](https://docs.beagleboard.org/latest/boards/beaglev/ahead/02-quick-start.html#beaglev-ahead-quick-start) by the BeagleBone team.

In short, at this point only the [Adafruit CP2102N Friend USB to Serial Converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5335) and the [Raspberry Pi Debug Probe Kit for Pico and RP2040](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5699) are known to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the image from [Beagle Board](https://www.beagleboard.org/distros) first to make sure it works.

Note that the BeagleV-Ahead serial port hardware seems to be problematic as found in beagle board forum, [this thread](https://forum.beagleboard.org/t/beaglev-ahead-debug-terminal-problems/35331).

Comment: issue was the same in the Yocto default image, and with the alternative Ubuntu image. as you said, the issue is with the serial port hardware. I linked known-working adapters in my solution below.